# Linked (sheaf, cosheaf)-pair on Alexandrov spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Sometimes a topologial space (X, $T_{open}$) has the property that its closed sets form a topology $T_{closed}$ too (Alexandrov space). In addition one has a sheaf $\mathcal{S}_{open }$ with respect to $T_{open}$ and a cosheaf $\mathcal{S}_{closed}$ on $T_{closed}$ with a certain functorial morphism $F: \mathcal{S}_{open} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}_{closed}.$

My question: Are there papers which study the homology and cohomology of such linked $(sheaf, cosheaf)$-pairs?  What's a suitable categorical setting?

Comment: Your first property (that the closed sets also form a topology) is satisfied iff the intersection of arbitrarily many opens is an open. A topological space with this property is called an Alexandrov space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thanks, I made an addition.